# Converting JSON with SQL - object and string for same property

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, data-conversion

I have a challenge converting a JSON array into a different output format using SQL Server...

Input:

```
[
    {
        "label": "City",
        "values": [
            "Test City"
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "imgTest",
        "values": [
            {
                "identifier": "56696553-48F4-4BC5-BB43-FF4F71743EE9",
                "filename": "file1.jpg",
                "contentType": "image/jpg",
                "bytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
            },
            {
                "identifier": "2D9106D7-71A1-440E-8255-679E8905B32E",
                "filename": "file2.jpg",
                "contentType": "image/jpg",
                "bytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "label": "City",
        "answer": "Test City"
    },
    {
        "label": "imgTest",
        "answer": {
            "filename": "file1.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpg",
            "bytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
        }
    },
    {
        "label": "imgTest",
        "answer": {
            "filename": "file2.jpg",
            "contentType": "image/jpg",
            "bytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
        }
    }
]
```

The challenge I find lies in the combination of a string and an object as the 'answer'-property in the output.

Note this is but a small subset of very much nested JSON input. Thanks.
Temporary tables etc are perfectly possible, as this would most likely happen via a stored procedure

Reason I am referring to SQL is because that is the technology I am most familiar with, and that has been used for these purposes successfully in the past.

My initial approach before the images came into play was to build a temp table with different layers of 'label-values'-pairs, and then turn this table into a json with a series of nested 'for json path' statements.

However, when I do this with the image-data, it assumes the content is string so it escapes the characters which causes an issue when sending the output to the next application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `FOR JSON` clause escapes the special characters in the JSON output with `\` and usually you can avoid this by using `JSON_QUERY()` (as is explained in the documentation *...JSON_QUERY returns a valid JSON fragment. As a result, FOR JSON doesn't escape special characters in the JSON_QUERY return value*).

As you already know, the problem here is that the `$."values"` part of the JSON contains a string and an object. A possible solution to this problem is to generate a table with two columns with the same name and apply the `FOR JSON AUTO` clause. The output of the `FOR JSON AUTO` is determined by a combination of the order of columns in the `SELECT` clause and the tables that are referenced in the `SELECT` clause, so I'm not sure if this output is "by design" or just an useful side effect. Of course, if you include the `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES` option, the result will include the values from both columns.

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
[
    {
        "label": "City",
        "values": [
            "Test City"
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "imgTest",
        "values": [
            {
                "identifier": "56696553-48F4-4BC5-BB43-FF4F71743EE9",
                "filename": "file1.jpg",
                "contentType": "image/jpg",
                "bytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
            },
            {
                "identifier": "2D9106D7-71A1-440E-8255-679E8905B32E",
                "filename": "file2.jpg",
                "contentType": "image/jpg",
                "bytes": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
            }
        ]
    }
]'
```

T-SQL:

```
SELECT 
   [label], 
   CASE WHEN ISJSON([value]) = 0 THEN [value] END AS [answer],
   JSON_QUERY(CASE WHEN ISJSON([value]) = 1 THEN [value] END) AS [answer]
FROM (
   SELECT j1.[label], j2.[value]
   FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
      [label] nvarchar(100) '$.label',
      [values] nvarchar(max) '$.values' AS JSON
   ) j1
   OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[values]) j2
) t   
FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Result:

```
[
   {
      "label":"City",
      "answer":"Test City"
   },
   {
      "label":"imgTest",
      "answer":{
         "identifier":"56696553-48F4-4BC5-BB43-FF4F71743EE9",
         "filename":"file1.jpg",
         "contentType":"image/jpg",
         "bytes":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
      }
   },
   {
      "label":"imgTest",
      "answer":{
         "identifier":"2D9106D7-71A1-440E-8255-679E8905B32E",
         "filename":"file2.jpg",
         "contentType":"image/jpg",
         "bytes":"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAgAAAAIAQMAAAD+wSzIAAAABlBMVEX///+/v7+jQ3Y5AAAADklEQVQI12P4AIX8EAgALgAD/aNpbtEAAAAASUVORK5CYII"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Zhorov. I was not aware of JSON AUTO allowing for multiple expressions with the same alias.
JSON PATH does not accept it, but I can workaround that requirement.